# Change Chrome's Default Cache Location

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, ssd, browser-cache

Here's the issue ... I have an ASUS gaming laptop and, for whatever reason, I've had the SSD drive fail on me *three* times.

I want as much "churn" off this drive as possible (just to be safe), and moved to my 1 TB mechanical drive.

I'm a software developer, and the only things I want on my C: SSD drive are Windows and my development tools.

I've [seen posts such as this](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/19/how-to-change-google-chromes-cache-location-and-size/) on how to move the cache location, but these are all command line switches and messing with the registry.  I also would prefer not to corrupt Chrome in the process.

Is there any "correct" way to do this?  Or should I just leave it alone?

If I re-install chrome to the mechanical drive, will this also have it cache to that drive?

Comment: Changing the chrome shortcut is the "official" way to move the cache. Another option would be to install a [portable version of chrome](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=50&q=portable+chrome&oq=portable+chrome) to the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't have that natively as a setting. You're going to have to use the command line arguments. I'm not sure why you would be concerned about "corrupting" Chrome by adding official Google command line arguments. The registry edit is just changing the file association when you double click on a link on your desktop.

The other thing you can do is move your user profile to the mechanical drive altogether using Windows. Since the cache is held in your local app data, this works for Chrome and any other apps that might be thrashing your SSD. IMHO, this is recommended for a few reasons - You don't have to worry about data filling up your SSD. You don't have to worry about excessive writes for any app. And mechanical drives are still easier to recover data from in case of disaster.

The downside is that Upgrading to Windows 8.1 won't work.

http://www.starkeith.net/coredump/2009/05/18/how-to-move-your-windows-user-profile-to-another-drive/